# AVR: do I have to wait for the internal pullup to stabilize?

Tags: avr, assembly

speaking of an ATMega2560 (not Arduino!), I connected a simple push-button between `PB6` and `GND`.

There is a bootloader and BOOTRST flag is set, i.e. the bootloader always starts first.

I want to use the button for skipping the bootloader, so I'm going to modify the bootloader:

```
//Defines for the guard button
#define GRD_PORT PORTB
#define GRD PB6

#define GRD_PIN GRD_PORT - 2
#define GRD_DDR GRD_PORT - 1

//Init guard button as input
cbi    GRD_DDR, GRD   ; clear PB6 in DDR -> making it input
sbi    GRD_PORT, GRD  ; set PB6 in PORT  -> enabling internal pullup

sbic   GRD_PIN, GRD   ; skip next if PB6 is cleared (low) in PIN register
jmp    my_app
```

But my problem is that `jmp` is always skipped, i.e it seems internal pullup enabling is slower and PINB6 still remains 0.

Is this valid? Do I have to initialize this port somehow different when using assembly?

Comment: Internal pull-ups are weak, so indeed they might take a while compared to MCU execution.  You could watch with a fast scope (use 10x probe mode to minimize the degree you disturb it by measuring).  You could also try adding time delay and see if that helps.  Or as an experiment add an *external* pullup and see if that changes things.

Comment: As an aside, it being an ATMega2560 has nothing to do with it being Arduino or not. You can use Arudino framework on a custom board or bare metal code (even assembly) on an Arduino board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need a delay for two reasons.

First of all, the internal pull-up is weak, so it can take a while before the voltage has risen enough to read as logic 1. How many clock cycles it takes depends on the stray capacitances.

Second reason is the input pin synchronizer, explained on datasheet page 70. The synchronization adds a delay, so even if you did toggle an output pin, you will need at least one NOP before you can read PIN register to see that the state has updated.

So most likely you need to add a delay loop which is the tightest code to achieve any arbitrary delay you want, due to weak pull up a few nops might not be enough.

Comment: From experience with the MCU in question, a minimum of three `nop` instructions (~16MHz) seems to reliably detect the pull-up change for a couple pF load (stray capacitances). For larger loads more time is advisable. In practice I'd go with at least 10 `nop` instructionas @16M as that gets you into the frequency range of FM+ I2C.